# Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V

Tags: java, maven, jasper-reports

### The Pre-Requisites

I have recently upgraded from JasperReports version **3.7.6** to **6.4.1**. JasperReports-fonts remains at version **5.6.1**. I have also made sure to update the core dependencies for each project, and they are now included in the Maven build.

I have a JavaSE-1.8 build path for my server, and this matches my environment too.

The updated Jasper Maven dependencies in the pom.xml are as follows.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>  

<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I realise this is a big version jump and we are bound to encounter some errors, but Maven builds and compiles the .jrxml report files **successfully**. However, I am getting an exception when trying to run the report from my client.

---

### The Exception

Message:

```
Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
```

Description:

```
The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:982)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
```

Root cause:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.<init>(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:149)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.getInstance(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:131)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.ensureFontExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:80)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:57)
net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:115)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:86)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:110)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:69)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:57)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:200)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:215)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:115)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:667)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:648)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:970)
```

Comment: This is usually a library version mismatch between the environment where you built the jar and the environment where you are running it.  In the build environment the method is concrete, but in the server environment the library is a different version where the method is abstract.  Please [edit] your post and indicate the versions of Java on the server and the build environment.

Comment: I have updated the post to reflect this. I still have the same problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error indicates that you have an old DOM/SAX implementation in your project.  Do you have a direct or transitive dependency to a parser such as Xerces?  If so, upgrade it to a newer version or remove it so that the parser included in the JRE is used.

Comment: Hi @dada67, your comment suggestion has resolved the problem. Please add an answer to this question, and I will accept as solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates that you have an old DOM/SAX implementation in your project.

You might have a direct or transitive dependency to a parser such as Xerces.

You should either upgrade the dependency to a newer version, or remove/exclude it so that the parser included in the JRE is used.